# Editing entries on multisite Craft CMS implementation

Tags: multi-site

We have a Craft CMS implementation with 3 sites enabled (multi-site). When I create an entry, it populates the entry to all 3 sites, which is fine. However, I would like to modify a link or content for only 1 of the sites. If I used the dropdown, select the site, then make my change and save, Craft still saves that change to all 3 mini sites.

Is editing 1 entry per minisite possible or do I have to create a duplicate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the field you are trying to change is set to be translatable.

Go to Settings → Fields → *Your field* → **Translation Method** and pick the suitable method for your site ([see documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/fields.html#translation-methods)).

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect!